# How to close the local sqlite database so that it can be deleted

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm implementing a 'reset database' function in a unit test project for a Windows (UWP) client of Azure Mobile Apps.    I would like to know how to close the connection to the SQLite database via the SDK so that I could delete the sqlite file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That functionality does not exist in the SDK.  You will need to file an issue on the GitHub repo and potentially implement it yourself.